# Why there is no expression sequencing operator?

Tags: c#, operators

As I cannot find the "comma operator" equivalent in the various operator tables (and tried to use it naturally because of C/C++ history) I suppose there is no such thing in C# specification at all. So I'm just curious, if there is any (simple) reason the C# does not allow expression sequencing in the C-like style?

```
var i = 1, 2, 3; // would evaluate 1, then 2, then 3 and assign evaluated 3 to i
```

Comment: Because its not in the language spec (this is a duplciate btw, I'll try and find the link). You can always just write three statements...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114443/is-there-idiomatic-c-sharp-equivalent-to-cs-comma-operator

Comment: There is a good reason its not in the language spec. Yikes, is it a good idea to overload `,` with a function?

Comment: The referenced "duplicate" does not answer my question, instead it gives other methods to reach the requested functionality. My question is: Why the C# designers did not include such operator in spec?

Comment: @Jodrell You just could write the reason or point me to source explaining it...

Comment: @sharpener I simply mean that its confusing to have a character that is sometimes a separator and sometimes an operator. I'm assuming the language specifiers decided to discard the confusion with the functionality. You can still do `var i = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }`, which is almost as easy to type but more explicit and therefore generally easier to understand.