# using ternary operator for multiple statement

Tags: c#-3.0

Can anybody help me to write ternary operator code for following code

```
if(s> b) 
{
  minlength = s.length;
  maxlength = b.length;
}
else
{
  minlength = b.length;
  maxlength = s.length;
}
```

i have tried the following code but it gives me an error

```
 s.Length > B.Length ? ( minlength = B.Length,maxlength = s.Length ) : ( minlength = s.Length, maxlength = B.Length);
```

when i use above code it gives an error

> "only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions
>   can be used as a statement"

Can anybody help me to resolve this...

Comment: Look at the: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114443/is-there-idiomatic-c-sharp-equivalent-to-cs-comma-operator  And why do you need such ugly code?

Answer (score 1):

why just write it in this way :

```
minlength = (s > b) ?  s.length : b.length;
maxlength = (s > b) ?  b.length : s.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use a ternary operator? I would have thought that a simple Math.Min/Max would be clearer to anyone reading it:

```
minlength = Math.Min(s.length, b.length);
maxlength = Math.Max(s.length, b.length);
```

...but that's just me :-)